# Implementing protected routing with react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Have created a react js dashboard app with the following versions
"react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0"

have to implement a protected routing instance for the app, as of react router v6 above protected routing is a bit different than i'm used to on v5. could someone show me how to add protected routing for this? Thank you for your time!

here's the app.js

```
import 'react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css';
import React from 'react';
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';
import GlobalStyles from 'src/components/GlobalStyles';
import 'src/mixins/chartjs';
import theme from 'src/theme';
import routes from 'src/routes';

const App = () => {
const routing = useRoutes(routes);

return (
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <GlobalStyles />
  {routing}
</ThemeProvider>
);
};
 export default App;
```

and here is the route.js code

```
const routes = [
{
path: 'app',
element: <DashboardLayout />,
children: [
  { path: 'account', element: <AccountView /> },
  { path: 'reporting', element: <CustomerListView /> },
  { path: 'dashboard', element: <DashboardView /> },
  { path: 'classrooms', element: <ProductListView /> },
  { path: 'settings', element: <SettingsView /> },
  { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> }
]
},
{
path: '/',
element: <MainLayout />,
children: [
  { path: 'login', element: <LoginView /> },
  { path: 'register', element: <RegisterView /> },
  {
    path: 'RegisterViewContactDetails',
    element: <RegisterViewContactDetails />
  },
  { path: 'ForgotPassword', element: <ForgotPassword /> },
  { path: 'RestPassword', element: <RestPassword /> },
  { path: '404', element: <NotFoundView /> },
  { path: '/', element: <Navigate to="/login" /> },
  { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> }
]
}
];
 export default routes;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my working example for implementing protected routes by using **useRoutes** hook.

App.js

```
import routes from './routes';
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  const routing = useRoutes(routes(isLoggedIn));

  return (
    <>
      {routing}
    </>
  );
}
```

routes.js

```
import { Navigate,Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

    const routes = (isLoggedIn) => [
      {
        path: '/app', // protected routes
        element: isLoggedIn ? <DashboardLayout /> : <Navigate to="/login" />,
        children: [
          { path: '/dashboard', element: <Dashboard /> },
          { path: '/account', element: <Account /> },
          { path: '/', element: <Navigate to="/app/dashboard" /> },
          {
            path: 'member',
            element: <Outlet />,
            children: [
              { path: '/', element: <MemberGrid /> },
              { path: '/add', element: <AddMember /> },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      { // public routes
        path: '/',
        element: !isLoggedIn ? <MainLayout /> : <Navigate to="/app/dashboard" />,
        children: [
          { path: 'login', element: <Login /> },
          { path: '/', element: <Navigate to="/login" /> },
        ],
      },
    ];
    
    export default routes;
```

Comment: mate the useSelector part is not a not defined output & about the implementation of isLoggedIn is that a component import?

Comment: useSelector is equivalent of map state to props(redux). I just keep user's authenticated status in the redux store.

Comment: Just pass the user's authenticated status in the place of isLoggedIn